# jQuery - select all elements with attribute name (not value) beginning with...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Say I'm looking for all elements with an attribute 'data-language', whose value begins with 'java' (would match both 'java' and 'javascript'). I know how to do this:

```
$('[data-language^="java"]')
```

But my question is: how do I get all elements that have an attribute (***not the value of the attribute, but the actual attribute name itself***) beginning with something? For example:

1. all elements that have an attribute name beginning with "data-s", or
2. all elements that have data attributes at all (attributes beginning with "data-").

Comment: I think we all mis-read this, you want to find all elements that have an attribute beginning with `data-`, so, you want all elements containing a custom data attribute, yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry, I can see how it could be misread.

Comment: I figured those bolded words meant something important :)

Comment: haha - ok, I've updated the question - hopefully it's a little clearer now.

Comment: _"I know how to get all elements that have an attribute value beginning with something: `$('[data-size^="value"]')`"_ That won't do that.

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean ? In this example the attribute has a name "data-size".

Comment: @dystroy - that sentence makes it sound like it will match all attributes that begin with "value" when it would only match data-size attributes where the value begins with "value". In the sentence, "an attribute" should be changed to "a data-size attribute"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no shortcut, you may use the `attributes` collection :

```
 $(someselector).filter(function(){
      var attrs = this.attributes;
      for (var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
          if (attrs[i].name.indexOf("someStartOfName")==0) return true;
      }         
      return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice function for this.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$("div").data() // returns all data attributes to this div
```

Comment: But this is data attributes for a particular element. I want to select all elements that have a data attribute.

Comment: yea after answering and rereading I realize this is not what you are looking for I believe @dystroy has it right for you

Comment: `$('div').filter(function () {
    return !$.isEmptyObject($(this).data())
})`  should fit your needs, matching any DIVs with some data attribute