# Selected and remove all matching data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find a way to remove from a page all matching data attributes from different kind of elements.

I now loop an array, but the list of names is to long therefor I hope there's a better way to remove my custom data attributes.....with a regex pattern?

// the code

```
var dataArr  = ['data-myplugin-value',
                'data-myplugin-id',
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
                'data-myplugin-name'];

$.each(dataArr, function(i,a){
   $('['+a+']').removeAttr(a);  
});
```

Comment: How do you get the array?

Comment: simple, i create the array my self ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using XPath, here is my solution:

```
function removeMyDataAttributes() {
    var list, iterator, attribute, i, n;

    // Select all attribute nodes that it's name starts with "data-myplugin-"
    iterator = document.evaluate('//*/attribute::*[starts-with(local-name(), "data-myplugin-")]', 
                    document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    list = [];
    while ((attribute = iterator.iterateNext())) {
        list.push(attribute);
        // Note: can't call removeAttributeNode here: 
        // InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The document has mutated since the result was returned.
    }
    for (i = 0, n = list.length; i < n; ++i) {
        attribute = list[ i ];
        attribute.ownerElement.removeAttributeNode(attribute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements share a common parent then you could narrow the search to this element:

```
var holder = $('#containerid');
$.each(dataArr, function(i,a){
    $('['+a+']', holder).removeAttr(a);  
});
```

There is some code at this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963305/jquery-select-all-elements-with-attribute-name-not-value-beginning-with) using the `attributes` collection, but I am not convinced that it would be any more efficient.

Comment: If appropriate you might consider setting the attribute-values to '' or some arbitrary value 'xxx', rather than removing the attribute entirely. But I've put this as a comment as I suspect the difference to be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think what you wrote above would work? You are treating the dataArr as DOM elements, which is wrong. Jquery would not be able to find

$('['+a+']').removeAttr(a);

as 'a' does not refer to an element.

Now, on how to solve it - i need one help - are these data attributes put in from jquery or part of html 5. If its through jquery, then you can use

[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.removedata/.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.removedata/)

It will work. So iterate over all DOM elements and call removeData(). Not the best solution but will work.

Comment: The example of my does work. But there should be a better, cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll look for one then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop through the array and remove all data attributes  
$.each(dataArr, function(i,a){
   removeDataAttributes('[+a+]');  
});

// removes all data attributes from a target element
// example:  removeDataAttributes('#user-list');
function removeDataAttributes(target) {

    var i,
        $target = $(target),
        attrName,
        dataAttrsToDelete = [],
        dataAttrs = $target.get(0).attributes,
        dataAttrsLen = dataAttrs.length;

    // loop through attributes and make a list of those
    // that begin with 'data-'
    for (i=0; i<dataAttrsLen; i++) {
        if ( 'data-' === dataAttrs[i].name.substring(0,5) ) {
            // Why don't you just delete the attributes here?
            // Deleting an attribute changes the indices of the
            // others wreaking havoc on the loop we are inside
            // b/c dataAttrs is a NamedNodeMap (not an array or obj)
            dataAttrsToDelete.push(dataAttrs[i].name);
        }
    }
    // delete each of the attributes we found above
    // i.e. those that start with "data-"
    $.each( dataAttrsToDelete, function( index, attrName ) {
        $target.removeAttr( attrName );
    })
};
```